# How can i solve error in ImageList variable say: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In form1 i have this in the designer the deisgner part is in form1 constructor:

```
this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
this.imageList1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ImageList(this.components);
this.imageList1.ImageStream = ((System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer)(resources.GetObject("imageList1.ImageStream")));
this.imageList1.TransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
this.imageList1.Images.SetKeyName(0, "");
```

Then i created a new User Control called it test.cs
And in the designer i added the same as in form1:

```
this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(ExplorerTree));
System.Windows.Forms.ImageList imageList1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ImageList(this.components);
imageList1.ImageStream = ((System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer)(resources.GetObject("imageList1.ImageStream")));
imageList1.TransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
imageList1.Images.SetKeyName(0, "");
```

In the User Control in the designer code the error i'm getting is on the line:

```
imageList1.Images.SetKeyName(0, "");
```

I don't see any red line under the line but in the error window i see in blue the symbol !
And the error is : Message  1   Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: '0' is not a valid value for 'index'.   C:\windowsexplorersource\TV-LV-Basic\ExplorerTree.Designer.cs   166 0

Message 1   Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: '0' is not a valid value for 'index'.   C:\windowsexplorersource\TV-LV-Basic\ExplorerTree.Designer.cs   166 0

Whay i'm getting this error in blue and how can i fix it ?

Comment: Have you added any Images??? You can't load Images using the Stream: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.imageliststreamer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): _However, you cannot use this class to load images to an ImageList control by directly assigning the ImageStream property from one ImageList. Instead you should directly assign one ImageList instance to another (for example, ImageList2 = ImageList1)._

Comment: Right i didn't add any images yet. Thanks.